# How to create a priority list of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

- list is below
- preference dictionary is below
- if all the keys and values except `type` will be same then ..
- Need to compare `type` in each list which is highest order in preference dictionary
- Output is list of dictionary which type is highest order

```
list_ = [
  {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "son",
    "email": "n@network.com",
    "type": "Owner"
  },
      {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "son",
    "email": "n@network.com",
    "type": "Manager"
  },
{
    "id": "21",
    "name": "abc",
    "email": "abc@network.com",
    "type": "Employ"
  },
{
    "id": "21",
    "name": "abc",
    "email": "abc@network.com",
    "type": "Manager"
  }
]
```

A preference dictionary = `{'Owner': 1, 'Manager':2, 'employ':3, 'HR': 4 }`

My expected output dictionary below

```
[{'id': '11', 'name': 'son', 'email': 'n@network.com', 'type': 'Owner'},
{'id':'21','name': 'abc','email': 'abc@network.com','type': 'Manager'}]
```

```
new_list = []
for each in list_:
    if each['type'] in priority.keys():
        if each['id'] not in new_list:
            new_list.append(each)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: According to your code I understand you are trying to sort the dictionary by the `type` key, is that correct?

Comment: @ThunderCoder yes, its

Comment: Your example does not include a reference to HR. What is HR?

Comment: `HR`, in the above example HR is not there, but it may come in different inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution groups all the elements by `id`, and sorts the groups according to the preference (so that the `Owner` is first and `HR` is last) and then just picks the first from each group:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

src = [
  {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "son",
    "email": "n@network.com",
    "type": "Owner"
  },
      {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "son",
    "email": "n@network.com",
    "type": "Manager"
  },
{
    "id": "21",
    "name": "abc",
    "email": "abc@network.com",
    "type": "Employ"
  },
{
    "id": "21",
    "name": "abc",
    "email": "abc@network.com",
    "type": "Manager"
  }
]
preference = {'Owner': 1, 'Manager':2, 'Employ':3, 'HR': 4 }

d = defaultdict(list)
# group all the records by id
for item in src:
    d[item['id']].append(item)

# sort each group by the preference
for item in d.values():
    item.sort(key=lambda x: preference[x['type']])

# select only the first from each group
result = [item[0] for item in d.values()]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': '11', 'name': 'son', 'email': 'n@network.com', 'type': 'Owner'}, {'id': '21', 'name': 'abc', 'email': 'abc@network.com', 'type': 'Manager'}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do `src.sort(key = lambda x : preference[x["type"]])` and your list will be sorted.

Comment: he wanted to remove the duplicate type as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a priority queue:

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

priority = {'Owner': 1, 'Manager':2, 'employ':3, 'HR': 4 }

q = PriorityQueue()
for elem in list_:
    p = priority[elem['type']]
    q.put((p, id(elem), elem))
```

Or you could also sort a list based on the `type` with:

```
priority_list = sorted(list_, key=lambda x: priority[x['type']], reverse=True)
```

Comment: can you explain little bit, i could not understood PriorityQueue

Comment: https://dbader.org/blog/priority-queues-in-python @sim

Answer (score 0):

Well here's my shot!

It isn't beautiful but it seems to work.

```py
list_ = [
  {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "son",
    "email": "n@network.com",
    "type": "Owner"
  },
      {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "son",
    "email": "n@network.com",
    "type": "Manager"
  },
{
    "id": "21",
    "name": "abc",
    "email": "abc@network.com",
    "type": "Employ"
  },
{
    "id": "21",
    "name": "abc",
    "email": "abc@network.com",
    "type": "Manager"
  }
]

new = dict( Owner = 0, Manager = 0, Employ = 0, HR = 0 )

for a in list_ :
    type_ = a[ 'type' ]
    if type_ == 'Owner':
        new[ 'Owner' ] += 1
    if type_ == 'Manager':
        new[ 'Manager' ] += 1
    if type_ in [ 'Employ', 'Manager' ]:
        new[ 'Employ' ] += 1
    new[ 'HR' ] += 1

print( new )
```